# DateTime.Parse: Cannot provide the value: host value not found

Tags: vb.net, date, datetime, parsing

I am trying to convert a string to a DateTime. the DateTime string may be provided in a different format so ideally I would like to not have to use DateTime.ParseExact().
The value of dateTime in the code below shows "Cannot provide the value: host value not found".

I have tried:

- Convert.ToDateTime()
- DateTime.Parse()
- DateTime.TryParse

What am I doing wrong and how do I correctly convert the string to a DateTime? thanks

```
Dim dateTimeString As String = "01/01/1900"
Dim dateTime = DateTime.Parse(dateTimeString)
```

Comment: By editing the question like that, it hid the part that [jmcilhinney answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60035693/1115360), so future readers would be confused. I rolled back the edit for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing that @jmcilhinney said (as a correct programming modus operandi), I think you are right in all in your conversion.
That seems a VS issue, so try update your VS-IDE OR try adding those two lines in Assembly.vb into your project folder.

```
<Assembly: DebuggerDisplay("{ToString}", Target:=GetType(Date))> 
<Assembly: DebuggerDisplay("{ToString}", Target:=GetType(Date?))>
```

Comment: Thanks. I updated VS2019 to the latest version and it now works

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that your attempt to refer to the `DateTime` type is actually failing because it is preferentially interpreted as the `dateTime` variable that you just declared.  Try using the inbuilt VB `Date` type instead, which is an alias for the .NET `DateTime` type.  If you use `Integer` rather than `Int32`, then you should already be using `Date` rather than `DateTime` to be consistent.

EDIT: I can't get the error message that you reported no matter what I do with that code. I can get it to generate a compilation error or a run-time exception with various settings for `Option Strict` and `Option Infer` though.  You should ALWAYS have `Option Strict On` except in the VERY rare cases that you need to use late-binding and, even then, you should set it `On` in the project properties and `Off` at the file level, using partial classes to keep the code in such files to an ABSOLUTE MINIMUM.  You should also probably have `Option Infer On` too, but it is by default, while `Option Strict` is `Off` by default.  You should set it `On` in the IDE options so that it will be `On` by default in future projects.

Comment: Thank you, I've made the changes you mention (see above). Unfortunately the issue is still there

Comment: Thank you for your help, it looks like this was a VS bug. I updated VS2019 to the latest version and it now works

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/786837/debug-in-visual-basic.html